# How to open files of unknown extensions?

Tags: windows-10

to be specific I want to see .dat and .dll files.

in general unknown file types. simple extensions like .ini, .bat work with notepad

I have tried notepad but it just shows gibberish. and I don't want to install a bunch of programs for a specific file type which I will rarely use

Comment: You are aware that .dll files are compiled code, correct?  This would be like opening a .exe file in a text editor.

Comment: Search google for programs that open `.dll` files in Windows, as there are many, and when opened, you'll be presented with a data tree. I'd assume `.dat` files would be a bit harder to nail down since I don't believe they're standardized and can contain anything; the best approach would likely be researching how to open a specific program's`.dat` files.

Comment: @JW0914 so you are saying that for every unknown extension, I should install a separate program. that will be a lot of programs, don't you think?

Comment: @Ramhound we can open .exe files directly but we can not open .dll files.

Comment: DLL don’t typically contain executable code.  You don’t have to install different programs if you know the content of the file.  Windows will let you open any file with any executable, that doesn’t mean, the executable supports that file extension

Comment: The X/Y question is probably more: WHY do you want to open `.dat` or `.dll` files? What prompts you to this need and what do you expect to achieve as goal?

Comment: @VIVEKSINGH Some extensions are standardized, whereas others are not, such as `.dat`, w/ many being specialized text files _(Scripts: `.sh`|`.bat`|`.cmd`|,`.ps1` || Configs: `.ini`|`.xml`/`.svg` || Compiling: `.c`|`.h` || Archive: `.tar` || etc.)_, so if the file only contains plain text, any notepad program can output it's contents, however for file extensions that don't contain data in plain text, the correct program must be used to read it, else it will appear as gibberish _(simply because a file extension stores data in plain text doesn't mean it won't appear nonsensical, such as `.tar`)_.

Comment: @VIVEKSINGH how many unknown extensions do you want to open? DLL isn't unknown at all and isn't what you typically want to "open", unless you're reverse engineering. If something is unknown why do you want to open it?

Answer (score 1):

`.dll` files for certain, and some `.dat` files, are program files designed to be used by the programs you run on your computer, and some `.dll` files are commonly used by more than one program (`.ini`, `.txt`, and `.bat` files all open with Notepad).

- `.dll` files are compiled code, so if you open them, they will look like nonsense (`ED FA BC` etc).

These files should not be opened or changed because you can damage the operating system if you do change them (this means repairing or reinstall the operating system), so it's best to leave these files alone.

Comment: i once opened a ,dll (imgres.dll) file on windows 7 using a hex editor it had images of lockscreen i was able to change that. yes the os may get corrupted but the satisfaction is amazing.

Comment: You can open a binary file with a HEX editor, but you can easily damage an OS changing it. Changing binary files by HEX editor is not how we manage our machines. There are always user tools for this.

Comment: @John Resource Hacker, and other programs like it, can open `.dll` files, with content displayed in a tree formation, similar to how the Registry is displayed. One common reason for opening a `.dll` is to get icons out of it. _(Resource Hacker's website does not provide an HTTPS link, hash, or GPG signature so downloading it from a trusted third-party site that has it, such as TechSpot, Bleeping Computer, etc., would be recommended)_